# socket binding failed with SO_REUSEADDR (address already in use)

Tags: c, sockets, bind

```
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &sz, sizeof(sz));

if(bind(s, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
      printf("%s bind failed: %s", __func__, strerror(errno));
      close(s);
      return -1;
}
```

OUTPUT:
open_uevent bind failed: Address already in use

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: You can try SO_REUSEPORT. See explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/socket-options-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-how-do-they-differ-do-they-mean-t

Comment: first google hit seems reasonable: http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/addrinuse.html

Comment: @Vasily, I got an error when I use SO_REUSEADDR instead.

Comment: @Sam, what operating system?

Comment: What is the definition  and value of sz? If it isn't an int, set non-zero, SO_REUSEADDR won't be set.

Comment: @Vasily, sorry for my fault. use SO_REUSEPORT i got the compile error. Both SO_RCVBUFFORCE and SO_REUSEADDR have the same error message "Address already in use"

Comment: @DoxyLover sz is set to 2048. I think this is a reasonable value. Isnt it?

Comment: #define EVENT_BUFFER_SIZE 2048
int sz = EVENT_BUFFER_SIZE;

Comment: I have no idea about this. : (

Comment: Is setsockopt() failing or succeeding?  It looks like you're not checking its return value, in which case you won't know that important piece of information...

Comment: I'd try to check address, may be it is really already bound by someone else? `printf("%s bind to %s:%d failed: %s", __func__, inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), ntohs(addr.sin_port), strerror(errno));`

Comment: @Jeremy setsockopt is succeeding.

Comment: @Vasily, thanks. let me give it a try.

Comment: @VasilyRedkin the structure is sockaddr_nl, it seems no addr and port member in its structure. How can obtain the address and port?

Comment: Woops. So this is *netlink* socket? Are you sure, SO_REUSEADDR has any meaning on it? Also, imho, your code should have root permissions for netlink socket to work - are you starting your app as root?

Comment: And please add your socket creation and `addr` initialization code. And may be adding "netlink" and "android" tags to question will help.